# Cannot in install Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04

I'm new to Linux. I created a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu 20.04.2 on windows.

During the installation process and after setting the network card with static IP address then selecting done, the system halted continuing with the installation with the screen displaying an error message,
"Sorry, there was a problem examining the storage devices on this system" I also tried with the latest version of Ubuntu 20.10 which resulted with the same error.

I'm using a Western Digital 500gb Hard Drive Blue Version.

Not sure what to do next. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Karl

Comment: What is the hard drive controller set for in the BIOS?  Anything other than AHCI or IDE can cause problems with seeing the drive.

Comment: Currently I have the SATA Mode Selected at IDE and IDE Legacy / Native Mode selected at Native.

Comment: Got it working by reformatting my hard drive.